# pandas plot - plot specific lines in file

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code for pandas plot. It takes in a file, and makes plots for specific lines (locus ID's: i.e. 'loc.27404').

However, this code manually specifies the lines which I want to plot.

I have a another file containing all the lines (there are 100s) that I want to plot - how can I write a script that will allow me to input this file such that so that these specific lines are plotted using the below code. I can't seem to write anything that makes sense.

```
data = {}
for line in File:
    cols = line.strip().split('\t')
    vals = map(float,cols[6:])
    data[cols[3]] = vals

fig,ax = plt.subplots(4,figsize=[15,20])

l1= 'loc.27404'
l2= 'loc.37387'
l3 = 'loc.05134'
l4 = 'loc.10034'

pd.Series(data[l1],index=xticks).plot(ax=ax[0])
pd.Series(data[l2],index=xticks).plot(ax=ax[1])
pd.Series(data[l3],index=xticks).plot(ax=ax[2])
pd.Series(data[l4],index=xticks).plot(ax=ax[3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution would be to read the 100s of lines and store results in a list, like: `['loc.27404','loc.37387','loc.05134','loc.10034']` to be used in a for-loop:

```
for i,line_to_plot in enumerate(['loc.27404','loc.37387','loc.05134','loc.10034']):
    pd.Series(data[line_to_plot],index=xticks).plot(ax=ax[i])
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Would there be a way to input the list file directly? I have generated a list of the lines I want to plot - the list format is: ['loc.00037'], ['loc.00225'], ['loc.00225'], ['loc.00257']

Comment: Did you try to convert ```[ ['loc.00037'], ['loc.00225'], ['loc.00225'], ['loc.00257'] ]``` to ```['loc.00037', 'loc.00225', 'loc.00225', 'loc.00257']``` using ```[x[0] for x in [ ['loc.00037'], ['loc.00225'], ['loc.00225'], ['loc.00257'] ]```?